# Integral closure of a subring that is a polynomial ring over an algebraically closed field.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field that is a subring of an integral domain $D$.  Assume $D$ contains an element $d$ that is transcendental over $K$.  Also assume that $D$ is integral over $K[d]$.  Must $K[d]$ be all of $D$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you pick $D= K[X]$ and $d = X^2$ then $D$ is integral over $K[d]$ but $K[d]$ is not all of $D$.